# Dynamic memory allocation in merge sort

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, dynamic, merge

I wrote a program for merge sort (i wrote the basic algorithm) - and it works fine. However, since  I have to read the integers from a very large file I wanted to declare the array dynamically in the recursive calls . hence i wrote the following code , however it is giving me some errors, could you please help me identify where i am making the mistake?

The program is actually to count the number of inversions in an array ( if i < j and arr[i]>arr[j] , then this is an inversion). The program I have written is as below :
I dont want to declare a array of 10000 integers on stack everytime i go in recursive calls

The error i get is : std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x004dd940..
i have edited the question so it includes the error message. The execution breaks and visual studio goes into debug mode and opens a file osfinfo.c

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    unsigned int mixAndCount(int * arr,int low, int mid,int high) {
        int *num = new int[high-low+1];// THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        int l = low ;
        int r = mid+1;
        unsigned int count=0;
        int i =low;

        while((l<=mid)&&(r<=high))
     {
      if(arr[l]<=arr[r])
      {
       num[i]=arr[l];
       l++;

      }
      else
      {
      num[i]=arr[r];
       r++;
       count=count + (mid-l+1);

      }
      i++;
         }
     if(l>mid)
     {
      for(int k=r;k<=high;k++)
      {
       num[i]=arr[k];
       i++;
        }
     }
     else
     {
      for(int k=l;k<=mid;k++)
      {
       num[i]=arr[k];
       i++;
        }
     }
     for(int k=low;k<=high;k++) arr[k]=num[k];
delete[] num;    
return count;
    }

    unsigned int mergeAndCount(int * arr, int low , int high ) {
        if(low>=high) {
        return 0;
        }
        else {
            int mid = (low+high)/2;

            unsigned int left = mergeAndCount(arr, low , mid);
            unsigned right = mergeAndCount(arr, mid+1, high);
            unsigned int split = mixAndCount(arr, low , mid , high);
            return left+right+split;

        }

    }
    int main ()
    {
        int  numArr[100000];
        FILE * input = fopen("IntegerArray.txt", "r");
        int i =0;
        while(!feof(input)) {
            int num;
        fscanf(input, "%d", &num);
        numArr[i] = num;
        i++;
        }
        fclose(input);
        unsigned int count = mergeAndCount(numArr,0, i-1  );
        cout<<count<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How can you ask to resolve compilation errors without actually posting the errors you are getting? This is not Hogwartz and there are no magic wand wizards here.

Comment: which errors does it give? Simply copy paste the error message please.

Comment: @gexicide : i have edited the question so it includes the error message. The execution breaks and visual studio goes into debug mode and opens a file osfinfo.c

Comment: Are you sure it is this line? The first line of your main already hauls a gigantic array onto the stack which might make it overflow right away.

Comment: @gexicide Yes I am sure, when i declare a stack normally on stack instead of dynamcically, my program runs smoothly

Comment: Why are you using `new int[]` instead of `std::vector<int>`? And signed integers for array indices, for that matter?

Answer (score 3):

```
 std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x004dd940..
```

Is an exception thrown by `new` when it cannot allocate requested memory successfully.

```
int *num = new int[high-low+1];
```

It seems the requested memory size is too large, which means you need to track values of `high`, `low`.

Comment: yeah, but why does that happen here? i mean the maximum memory that i am asking for is 100000 integers, which isn't too big for the heap...

Comment: @RohitAgrawal: How did you decide it is not too big for heap? Does your program work by reducing the requested memory?

Comment: high and low are at the maximum 0 and 99999 and that too in one case. and i am deleting the requested memory before exiting the function

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of dynamic memory allocation. Its really slower. Consider twice before you will leave your code in this form. You can make a simple testcase with `std::chrono`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration

you dont need dynamic allocation, everything is done in one local namespace.